# Отображение синонимов меток в подсказке

Tags: дефект, синонимы-меток

Есть метка [сеть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c). У нее есть синонимичная метка [компьютерные-сети](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d1%8c%d1%8e%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8). Вопрос: почему когда я начинаю вводить метку `сет` я вижу отдельно метку [компьютерные-сети](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d1%8c%d1%8e%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8) с 14 вопросами?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Есть вопрос [Incorrect number of questions shown on tag mouseover](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323744/339911), где разбирается причина несогласованного количества вопросов по синонимизированным меткам. В ответе указывается на то, что метки сининимизированы, но не объединены (merged). Скорее всего, похожая ситуация возникает и здесь. В выпадающем списке содержатся метки, где в названии есть введённая подстрока, в данном случае «сет». А 14 - это количество вопросов, заданных с меткой [компьютерные-сети](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d1%8c%d1%8e%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8) до её синонимизации с меткой [сеть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c).

Подробнее о различии синонимизации от объединения можно ознакомиться [здесь](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263959/339911).